# Software version names

Tags: nouns, names, list-order

For different major releases of a software product it is nice to assign a name to them. Although I find this tough...

Properties of a *good* software version name:

- relatively large group of nouns (so you have options for future releases)
- an order to them

For example:

- Planets : Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune, etc. ? <sup>* arguably too small a list</sup>
- Elements : Hydrogen, Helium, Lithium, etc.

What other name options exist?

Comment: I think the best you're going to get without losing meaning with respect to versions is something simpler such as an alphabetical naming system, like they do with hurricanes.

Comment: sweets, or maybe big cats and mountains?  that should catch on

Comment: Requests for naming is off topic.

Comment: Planets and elements are simply too boring to be used. Choose something original with at least some relevance and/or interest to the people involved in the project.

Comment: Also sometimes the names chosen are deliberately picked so they are ordered alphabetically in same time-order as the releases.

Comment: Sorry @JasonBassford , I wasn't very clear, I'm not after a name per se. As I think k1eran noticed I'm after other categories of things that have an implicit order. Or even a greater term that describes this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of options to choose from, but this is going to be more of a branding decision than anything else.  My personal favorite list of major release names is for the statistical computing and graphics language, R. [They are Peanuts comic references](http://livefreeordichotomize.com/2017/09/28/r-release-names/):

My favorites:

- Very Secure Dishes
- Supposedly Educational
- You Stupid Darkness
- Kite-eating Tree

May I suggest using Calvin & Hobbes references*? Or perhaps episode names from your favorite TV show.

*Your beta could be: "I just don't test well"

[image]

Other Calvin & Hobbes references that make good version names:

- Philosopher's sled
- Transmogrifier
- Evolved from a snowball

Comment: Love the idea, although unless you follow comic order, these don't really have an order to them

Answer (score 0):

Greek Alphabets could be also an option

```
alpha
beta 
gamma
....
```

and yet it also got list of only 24